# Redirect handling in htmlUnit

Tags: c#, htmlunit

How can I get the current page, when it was redirected?
If I send the form or server redirect me..

UPD
webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage(); work perfectly for me. Thank all!

Comment: What Do You want from Current page?

Comment: Does htmlUnit have a setting to follow redirects?

Answer (score 1):

by default, Webclient is set to redirect pages on request by server. Why don't you disable the option
wClient.setRedirectEnabled(false);